# Android MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Tags: java, android, listview, swipe, motionevent

im trying to implement swipe for my list view item, i have hidden element (like a button ) 
i want swipe left/right item for showing this button. Everything work perfect. Except i cant click normally on item or button. Because event MotionEvent.ACTION_UP always triggered.
Log when i just make simple click/touch on item

```
 Action DOWN
 OLD X = -329.0
 DX = -329.0
 MOVE RIGHT
 OLD X = -329.0
 DX = -330.5
 MOVE RIGHT
 OLD X = -329.0
 DX = -330.95996
 MOVE RIGHT
 Action UP
```

Can any help me ?
For click on items im trying to use this code

```
float cx = event.getX();
  if(cx<width && cx>(width-150)) {
```

and my code

```
swipeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private boolean canClick = false;


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        x1 = event.getX();
                        dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                        Logger.e("Action DOWN");
                        oldX = dX;
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        Logger.e("OLD X = " + oldX);
                        Logger.e("DX = " + dX);
                        dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        if (oldX < dX) {
                            Logger.e("MOVE LEFT");
                            view.animate().x(-100).setDuration(50).start();
                            break;
                        }

                        if (oldX > dX) {
                            Logger.e("MOVE RIGHT");
                            view.animate().x(0).setDuration(50).start();
                            break;
                        }


                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Logger.e("Action UP");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use [Gesture Detector](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) along with touch listener to process the touch response.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`GestureDetector`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) to handle swiping.
Here is the possible example:

```
new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                    float velocityY) {
                // Here you handle short quick swipe gesture
                return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                    float distanceY) {
                // Here you handle slow finger movement across the screen
                return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
            }
        });
```